# How to use Aggregate function in R

Tags: r, aggregation

can you help me please how to properly use aggregate function in R?
I have data like this:

```
SPORT   FLOWS
[1,] "Other" "1"  
[2,] "Other" "1"  
[3,] "Other" "1"  
[4,] "Other" "1"  
[5,] "Other2" "1"  
[6,] "Other2" "1"
```

And I need to get this:

```
SPORT   FLOWS
[1,] "Other" "4"
[2,] "Other2" "2"
```

I found, that it can be done with aggregate function, but it doesn't work..

Thank you guys.. I have marked answer which worked for me..

Comment: Your biggest problem is that `FLOWS` is of type `character`

Comment: Also, you may be interested in the plyr package for collapsing data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
aggregate(FLOWS ~ SPORT, dat, function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))
```

where `dat` is the name of your matrix.

Here, the function `is.numeric` is necessary to transform the second column into numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dataframe is named "sport_data", I think you just want:

```
aggregate(sport_data, sport_data$SPORT, sum)
```

If you just have individual counts (that are all equal to 1), then "tabulate" may be a simpler option.

Please let us know what kind of errors you are getting. (if this doesn't work, or in the future, in your question)

Answer (score 0):

Try Aggregate function in r

```
test <- aggregate(df[,4:5] ,by=list(df$name),sum)
```