# R: Mean of subvectors based on repeats in another vector

Tags: r, vector, subset, mean

I am trying to make two subvectors equal length from two vectors equal length.

Values in first vector are ordered as follows:

```
 a<-c(9,9,9,8,8,7,6,5,5,5)
```

Second vector is random, but lets take

```
 b<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

The first subvector is simple:it is just the vector `a` withouth repeats

```
 f(a)<-c(9,8,7,6,5)
```

The second subvector should be made as follows:
for single value in vector `a` (no repeats in `a`)the vector `g(b)` has the same value as vector `b` on corresponding position. For repeats in `a` the `g(b)` value should be mean of values from corresponding subvector `b`. So:

```
g(b)<-c(mean(c(1,2,3)), mean(c(4,5)), 6, 7, mean(c(8,9,10)))
```

I have no idea where to start. Thx for help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Aggregate function in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620764/how-to-use-aggregate-function-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tapply` is the function you want. See `?tapply` to see how it works. Here:

```
res<-tapply(b,a,mean) 
#  5   6   7   8   9 
#9.0 7.0 6.0 4.5 2.0
```

If you want to preserve the order:

```
tapply(b,a,mean)[as.character(unique(a))]
#  9   8   7   6   5 
#2.0 4.5 6.0 7.0 9.0
```

As you can see, it gives the `unique` values of `a` and for each of them, the desired function (in this case `mean(b)`) is evaluated.

Comment: the problem is that tapply change the original order of the keys (it sorts them ascending)

Comment: @digEmAll Why is that a problem?

Comment: Simples solutions are easiest to overlook. Thx!

Comment: @nicola: sometimes it is a problem, maybe not in this case

Answer (score 1):

You can do in this way:

```
uniqueA <- a[!duplicated(a)] # or simply unique(a) but I'm not sure about order preservation
uniqueB <- as.numeric(by(b,match(a,uniqueA),mean))

> uniqueA
[1] 9 8 7 6 5
> uniqueB
[1] 2.0 4.5 6.0 7.0 9.0
```

Comment: `unique` preserves the order. See `?unique` and check the `fromLast` argument. Try for instance the difference between `unique(c(1,3,1))` and `unique(c(1,3,1),fromLast=TRUE)`.

Comment: @nicola: Thanks, I had a quick look at the documentation but I missed that ;)

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `ave`

```
unique(ave(b, a))
#[1] 2.0 4.5 6.0 7.0 9.0
```

Or another option would be to convert the 'b' to `factor` with `levels` specified

```
tapply(b, factor(a, levels=unique(a)), FUN=mean)
#  9   8   7   6   5 
#2.0 4.5 6.0 7.0 9.0
```